# airflow best way to handle async function as task

Tags: python, airflow

I have a dag like this:

```
from datetime import timedelta
import pendulum
from airflow.decorators import dag
from stage import stage_data
from table_async_pg import merge_data

@dag(
dag_id = "data-sync",
schedule_interval = "1 * * * *",
start_date=pendulum.datetime(2023, 3, 8, tz="Asia/Hong_Kong"),
catchup=False,
dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=20),
)
def Pipeline():
    a = stage_data()
    b = merge_data()

    a >> b


pipeline = Pipeline()
```

`merge_data` is an async function that looks like that:

```
import psycopg
from config import config
import asyncio
from airflow.decorators import task

URI = f'postgresql://{config.USER_PG}:{config.PASS_PG}@{config.HOST_PG}:{config.PORT_PG}/{config.DATABASE_PG}'

@task
async def merge_data():
    try:
        async with await psycopg.AsyncConnection.connect(URI,autocommit=True) as aconn:
            async with aconn.cursor() as cur:
                       await cur.execute("""
                       TRUNCATE TABLE host CASCADE
                       """)
        
        return 0
    except Exception as e:
        return 1
```

I think it's not valid to return a coroutine so I wrapped into a try exception block to return 0 or 1.However I still get the error message:

```
    CLASSNAME: o.__module__ + "." + o.__class__.__qualname__,
AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute '__module__'
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'merge_data' was never awaited
```

Comment: Do you want to use `psycopg` or can you use `PostgresOperator`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating a task for every merge? Instead of running async functions, for Airflow it's best to run separate tasks and each task will display in a separate worker node (box on diagram). You can even define the concurrency of how many are running at the same time. I would personally do something like this:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.postgres.operators.postgres import PostgresOperator
from datetime import timedelta
import pendulum

with DAG(
    dag_id = "data-sync",
    schedule_interval = "1 * * * *",
    start_date=pendulum.datetime(2023, 3, 8, tz="Asia/Hong_Kong"),
    catchup=False,
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=20),
):

for table in tables:
    stage =  PostgresOperator(
                  task_id=f"stage_{table}",
                  sql=stage_sql.format(table)
               )

    merge =  PostgresOperator(
                  task_id=f"merge_{table}",
                  sql=merge_sql.format(table)
               )

    stage >> merge
```